# Shortening up respond_with( :include => xxx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include, arel, respond-with

I'm looking for a way to shorten up the :include => :child inside a respond_with which generates json.

Here is an example, not sure if it is even possible, but I would like to find out.

In the controller:

```
@p = Parent.where('id = ?', params[:id])
respond_with(@p, :include => {:child1 => {}, :child2 => {}, :child3 => {:include => :grandchild1}})
```

Is there someway to include these all when I define the instance?

Maybe something like:

```
@p = Parent.includes(:child1, :child2, :child3, :grandchild1).where('id = ?', params[:id])
respond_with(@p)
```

Basically, I'm trying to DRY up my code ... I don't want to have to keep typing the include hash over and over ... Is there someway to just include all child objects in one call?

Comment: child1, child2 and child3 are associations of Parent? and grandchild1 is an association of child3?

Comment: Yes Thilo, that would be correct. The children and grandchildren will vary depending on the model, so I was looking for something that could be used somewhat like a helper method ... But I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 5):

ActiveRecord has an as_json method that defines how the object should be outputted as json. You can ovveride this method to include the associated children by default so something like this:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  # We went to display grandchildren by default in the output JSON
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(:include => {:child1 => {}, :child2 => {}, :child3 => {:include => :grandchild1}})
  end


end
```

That should let you clean up your controller a bit, you only need this:

```
@parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
respond_with @parent
```

Comment: Hi Mario, I'm not sure that overriding the as_json method would work here. There could be any number of associations that I would be using. So, not sure that this would work, unless, I could enter the various children and grandchildren through the options, but that would be the same as using the original code, am I wrong?

Comment: If you're going to be using different options then yes you'll need to add them to the respond with statement like your original code above.

Comment: you'd probably want `options.reverse_merge` there to have the intended effect.